# redirect domain.com to www.domain.com with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

How to redirect an 'empty' subdomain http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com using htaccess rewrite engine. It has to be a 301 permanent redirect and convey the rest of the url and query string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The query string gets automatically appended.

Comment: this will add additional www if you type www.domain.com

Comment: @SaravanaDev no it won't, because of this condition: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$`. It specifically makes it so there must not be a www. Additionally, the targeted URL that you get redirected to doesn't specifically says "www.domain.com", it's not tacking on any additional "www"'s.